# Normalising the remaining decimal of a number?

Tags: javascript, numbers, normalization

I have a counter that goes up by `0.33` on each iteration. What's the best way of normalising the output such that the remaining decimal is either `.33`, `.66` or `.99` depending on its logical iteration?

On the left is my counter after each iteration, and on the right shows how I would like it normalised:

```
iteration / decimal / normalised

0       >       .33     >   .33
1       >       .66     >   .66
2       >       .99     >   .99
3       >       1.32    >   1.33
4       >       1.65    >   1.66
5       >       1.98    >   1.99
6       >       2.31    >   2.33
7       >       2.64    >   2.66
8       >       2.97    >   2.99

...

170     >       56.1    >   56.99
171     >       56.43   >   57.33
172     >       56.76   >   57.66
173     >       57.09   >   57.99
```

Note that, further down the line of iterations, `56.1` is `170` iterations of `.33` (`56.1 / .33 = 170`), therefore its logical ending is `.99`, because it is the last in the series of 3 (`170 % 3 = 2`).

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Mpe9/) that summarises the iteration logic.

Comment: @zerkms—yeah, I missed the point… :-(

Comment: Probably the worst question I've ever asked. It was late and my brain wasn't working. I'm voting to close it myself...

Answer (score 0):

```
var increment = 1/3;
var start = 0;
while(true) {
    start += increment;
    alert(start);
}
```

Unless you need amazing precision into thousands of iterations the above code should solve your problem.

Otherwise I suggest to use integers for exact precision.

```
var increment = 1;
var start = 0;
while(true) {
    start += increment;
    alert(start/3);
}
```

Comment: A bit unpleasant to suggest an endless loop. The OP's iterator (which is not shown) doesn't appear to return even multiples, hence the rounding requirement. This will return values like 0.3333333333333333 and 0.6666666666666666.

Comment: Wow RobG you're out for blood tonight. He mentioned he was comfortable with pseudo code. while(true) is a common way to show something is looping in pseudo code.

Comment: You seem to have missed the point (like I did initially), the OP is after some weird rounding to set values, not a simple arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be a okay

```
function CreateSeries()
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        document.write(i + .33);
        document.write(i + .66);
        document.write(i + .99);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I did not explain the logical iterations particularly well in my initial question, but I have found that the simplest way to normalise the numbers in the desired way is to use the following:

```
function normalise(input){

    var output = ( Math.floor((input / .33) / 3)) + ((((input / .33) % 3) + 1) * .33 );

    return Number(output.toFixed(2));

}
```

This has the desired results:

```
iteration : output

0 : 0.33
1 : 0.66
2 : 0.99
3 : 1.33
4 : 1.66
5 : 1.99
6 : 2.33
7 : 2.66
8 : 2.99
9 : 3.33
10 : 3.66

...

100 : 33.66
101 : 33.99
102 : 34.33
103 : 34.66
104 : 34.99
105 : 35.32

...

165 : 55.33
166 : 55.66
167 : 55.99
168 : 56.33
169 : 56.66
170 : 56.99
```

An [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Uw6fr/2/) of the method in action.